# Text with border line and takes remaining width

Tags: html, css

How can I achieve the text and right border line with pure CSS? Check below sample image.

The body has a background image. I have made the line using `::after`, but I can't dynamically calculate the gap between text and border line from the left. I can set a fixed width for the gap if the text is static. But how can I do it when the text is dynamic?

[image]

---

```css
body,
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  background-image: url(http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/7-flower-wallpaper.jpg);
}
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
h1::after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 80%;
  left: 160px;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>About us</h1>
```

Comment: just making sure: you are looking for a pure CSS answer, no JS/jQuery?

Comment: Yes looking for pure css :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26275946/1781026

Comment: Yes, it's the trick is working.. and I answered my own question below with my requirement. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try using flexbox. Set he `h1` to `display:flex`, it turns the text "About us" and the `::after` pseudo element to flex items, with `flex:1` on the 2nd one for taking the max remaining width available. Lastly, adjust the position as needed.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/7-flower-wallpaper.jpg);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
}
h1::after {
  flex: 1;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: 6px;
  top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<h1>About us</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the solution, check below snippet

```css
body,
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  background-image: url(http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/7-flower-wallpaper.jpg);
}
h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1::after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>About us</h1>
```